# Checkbox ajax event not triggerd

Tags: checkbox, primefaces

I have the following code that is not working.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="make" value="#{priceList.searchMakeId}"   >
                                <p:ajax event="click" process="@form" update="recordCountPanel" immediate="true" listener="#{priceList.reCountRecords}" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{priceList.vehicleMakeItems}" />
                            </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Bean method

```
public void reCountRecords() throws MWSException {
```

The method is never called. When I replace the p:selectManyCheckbox with h:electManyCheckbox or with p:selectManyMenu Then when clicking/changing these components, the bean method is called.

I can't find in the generated shtml source any onlclick or onchange event on the primefaces checkbox.

So I'm guessing something is not rendered correctly when I use p:selectManyCheckbox

But since I don't have any errors on my server or in browsr javascript I'm clueless of what is causing the problem. 
I tried with primefaces 6.0    6.1.6 and 6.1.8 . All the same result. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Tried different events?

Comment: And tried running in development mode: https://www.google.nl/search?q=jsf+development+mode

Comment: tried click and change event. Tried without specifieing the event. Tried in developement mode as well. All same result

Comment: No explicit errors client or server-side when running in dev mode?

Comment: no, no errors, not in regular mode, not in development mode. Not in my own log (log4j) not in javascript in browser, not on server log (wildfly-10.1.0.Final)

Comment: Let me check tonight then in my own pet/play project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out one of my collegues wrote a custom rendere for the selectManyCheckbox. But did it for PF 3 (some issues with responsive designs) And it was never updated and since I updated to PF6 it caused problems. Removing the custom rendere fixed the issue I had and also fixed the problem with the responsive design.